# What are the folders 'burstlyImageCache' and 'burstlyVideoCache' and can I delete them?

Tags: file-system, file-management

I'm interested in the following two folders found on my Samsung SIII:

- `/storage/sdcard0/burstlyImageCache`
- `/storage/sdcard0/burstlyVideoCache`

Together they only come to about 1.5 MB on my device.

What application creates these, and can they be safely removed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're cache directories that hold Ads for games. I've read Angry Birds is one such game that uses those directories.

Yes, you could delete them, but they'll keep coming back everytime a game reloads their Ads.

Comment: Is there a way I could use the underlying file system to block the game's ability to write to these folders? I'm guessing I'd have to root my phone...

Comment: There probably is a way, but in doing so you could inadvertently make the game or app unstable. Another option is to use something like [Adblock](http://adblockplus.org/en/android-about) which would block the app/game being able to get the ad content in the first place

Comment: You could try using Tasker to clear the folder periodically, or perhaps even when Angry Birds stops.